# Generic RedBlack Driver

Tags: java, generic-programming, red-black-tree

I'm Trying to insert data threw my driver but it is nothing is working I keep getting my inset highlighted red and telling me that it is not the correct data type.The main problem is I don't understand how to set a generic type Node.Thank you for your help.
Driver(I've been trying diffrent things no progrees):

```
public class Driver {
    public static <E> void main(String[] args){
          RedBlack<Integer> rb = new RedBlack<Integer>( );
          Node<Integer> item=32;
          rb.insert(item);
       }//close main
}//close driver
```

REDBLACK CODE:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class RedBlack<E extends Comparable<? super E>>{
////////////////////////////////SETUP//////////////////////////////////////////   
   private final static int Red=0;             
   private final static int Black=1;
   private Node<E> nil;
   private Node<E> root;

   public RedBlack() {
      nil=new Node<E>(null);
      nil.left=nil.right=nil;
      root=new Node<E>(null);
      root.left=root.right=nil;
   }


   static class Node<E>{
      Node(E theData){
         this(theData,null,null);
      }

      Node(E theData,Node<E> lt,Node<E> rt){
            data=theData;
            left=lt;
            right=rt;
            color=RedBlack.Black;
      }

      E data;              // The data in the Node
      Node<E> left;        // Left child
      Node<E> right;       // Right child
      Node<E> parent;      // Above Node 
      int color=Black;     // Color of Node
   }
////////////////////////////////INSERT////////////////////////////////
   public void insert(Node<E> item) {
      if(item==null) {
         throw new NoSuchElementException("Inset was null");
      }//close if
      Node<E> temp=root;
      if(root==nil) {
         root= item;
         item.color=Black;
         item.parent=nil;
      }//close if
      else {
         item.color=Red;
         while(item!=root) {
            if(compare(item.data,temp.data)<0) {
               if(temp.right==nil) {
                  temp.right=item;
                  item.parent=temp;
                  break;
               }//close if
               else {
                  temp=temp.right;
               }//close else
            }//close if
            else if(compare(item.data,temp.data)>0){
               if(temp.left==nil) {
                  temp.left=item;
                  item.parent=temp;
                  break;
               }//close if
               else {
                  temp=temp.left;
               }//close else
            }//close else if
         }//close while
         adjustment(item);
      }//close else
   }//close insert

   private void adjustment(Node<E> item) {
      while(item.parent.color==Red) {
         Node<E> uncle;
         if(item.parent==item.parent.parent.left) {
            uncle=item.parent.parent.right;
            if(uncle.color==Red && uncle!=nil) {   //the uncle needs to exist and and be red to recolored
               item.parent.color=Black;
               item.parent.parent.color=Red;
               uncle.color=Black;
               continue;
            }//close if
            if(item==item.parent.right) {
               item=item.parent;
               lR(item);
            }//close if
            item.parent.color=Black;
            item.parent.parent.color=Red;
            rR(item.parent.parent);
         }//close if
         else {
            uncle=item.parent.parent.left;
            if(uncle.color==Red&&uncle!=nil) {
               item.parent.color=Black;
               item.parent.parent.color=Red;
               uncle.color=Black;
               continue;
            }//close if
            if(item==item.parent.left) {
               item=item.parent;
               rR(item);
            }//close if
            item.parent.color=Black;
            item.parent.parent.color=Red;
            lR(item.parent.parent);
         }//close else
      }//close while
      root.color=Black;
   }//close adjustment

   private int compare(E item,E x) {
      if(x==root) {
         return 1;   //same as root will be placed on the right
      }//close if
      else return item.compareTo(x);
   }//close compare
////////////////////////////////ROTATE////////////////////////////////
   private void rR(Node<E> node) {
      if(node.parent!=nil) {
         if(node==node.parent.left) {
            node.parent.left=node.left;
         }//close if
         else {
            node.parent.right=node.left;
         }//close else
         node.left.parent=node.parent;
         node.parent=node.left;
         if(node.left.right!=nil) {
            node.left.right.parent=node;
         }//close if
         Node<E> left=root.left;
         root.left=root.left.right;
         left.right.parent=nil;
         root=left;
      }//close if
   }//close rR
   private void lR(Node<E> node) {
      if(node.parent!=nil) {
        if(node==node.parent.left) {
           node.parent.left=node.right;
        }//close if
        else {
           node.parent.right=node.right;
        }//close else
        node.right.parent=node.parent;
        node.parent=node.parent;
        if(node.right.left!=nil) {
           node.right.left.parent=node;
        }//close if
        node.right=node.right.left;
        node.parent.left=node;
      }//close if
      else {
         Node<E> right=root.right;
         root.right=right.left;
         right.left.parent=root;
         root.parent=right;
         right.left=root;
         right.parent=nil;
         root=right;
      }//close else
   }//close lR      
////////////////////////////////DELETE////////////////////////////////  
   public void delete(Node<E> node) {
      if((node=find(node,root))==null) {
         System.out.println("Node does not exist");
         return;
      }
      Node<E> node2;
      Node<E> temp=node;
      int tempColor=node.color;

      if(node.left==nil) {
         node2=node.right;
         switchNodes(node,node.right);
      }
      else if(node.right==nil) {
         node2=node.left;
         switchNodes(node,node.left);
      }
      else {
         temp=subTree(node.right);
         tempColor=temp.color;
         node2=temp.right;
         if(temp.parent==node) {
            node2.parent=temp;
         }
         else {
            switchNodes(temp,temp.right);
            temp.right=node.right;
            temp.right.parent=temp;
         }
         switchNodes(node,temp);
         temp.left=node.left;
         temp.left.parent=temp;
         temp.color=node.color;
      }
      if(tempColor==Black) {
         deleteAdjustment(node2);
      }
   }//close delete

   public void switchNodes(Node<E> node,Node<E> nodeOther) {
      if(node.parent==nil) {
         root=nodeOther;
      }
      else if(node==node.parent.left) {
         nodeOther.parent.left=nodeOther;
      }
      else {
         node.parent.right=nodeOther;
      }
      nodeOther.parent=node.parent;
   }

   public Node<E> subTree(Node<E> subRoot) {
      while(subRoot!=nil) {
         subRoot=subRoot.left;
      }
      return subRoot;
   }

   public void deleteAdjustment(Node<E> node) {
      while(node!=root && node.color==Black) {
         if(node==node.parent.left) {
            Node<E> brother=node.parent.right;
            if(brother.color==Red) {
               brother.color=Black;
               node.parent.color=Red;
               lR(node.parent);
               brother=node.parent.right;
            }//close if
            if(brother.left.color==Black && brother.right.color==Black) {
               brother.color=Red;
               node=node.parent;
               continue;
            }//close if
            else if(brother.right.color==Black) {
               brother.left.color=Black;
               brother.color=Red;
               rR(brother);
               brother=node.parent.right;
            }//close else if
            if(brother.right.color==Red) {
               brother.color=node.parent.color;
               node.parent.color=Black;
               brother.right.color=Black;
               lR(node.parent);
               node=root;
            }//close if
         }//close if
         else {
            Node<E> brother=node.parent.left;
            if(brother.color==Red) {
               brother.color=Black;
               node.parent.color=Red;
               rR(node.parent);
               brother=node.parent.left;
            }//close if
            if(brother.right.color==Black&&brother.left.color==Black) {
               brother.color=Red;
               node=node.parent;
               continue;
            }//close if
            else if(brother.left.color==Black) {
               brother.right.color=Black;
               brother.color=Red;
               lR(brother);
               brother=node.parent.left;
            }//close else if
            if(brother.left.color==Red) {
               brother.color=node.parent.color;
               node.parent.color=Black;
               brother.left.color=Black;
               rR(node.parent);
               node=root;
            }//close if
         }//close else
      }//close while
      node.color=Black;
   }//close deleteAdjustment
////////////////////////////////FIND////////////////////////////////

   public Node<E> find(Node<E> item) {
      if(item==null) {
         throw new NoSuchElementException("Item was null.");
      }//close if
      return find(item,root);
   }//close find

   private Node<E> find(Node<E> findNode,Node<E> node) {
      if(root==nil) {
         return null;
      }//close if
      if(compare(findNode.data,node.data)<0) {
         if (node.right != nil) {
            return find(findNode,node.right);
         }
      }
      else if(compare(findNode.data,node.data)>0) {
         if (node.left != nil) {
            return find(findNode,node.left);
         }//close if
      }//close if
      else if(findNode.data==node.data) {
         return node;
      }
      return null;
   }

////////////////////////////////Print////////////////////////////////

   public void printInOrder() {
      if(root==nil) {
         return;
      }//close if
      System.out.print("Key: "+root.data+"-Black");
      printTree(root);
   }//close printInOrder

   public void printTree(Node<E> node) {
      if(node==nil) {
         return;
      }//close if
      printTree(node.left);
      if(node.color==Black) {
         System.out.print("Key: "+node.data+"-Black");
      }//close if
      else {
         System.out.print("Key: "+node.data+"-Red");
      }//close else
      printTree(node.right);
   }//close printTree
}//close class
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is

```
Node<Integer> item=32;
```

This should be

```
Node<Integer> item = new Node<>(32);
```

That creates a new `Node` with the value 32.

Also, remove the `<E>` in the declaration of the `main()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In your red uncle code:

```
    if(uncle.color==Red && uncle!=nil) {   //the uncle needs to exist and and be red to recolored
       item.parent.color=Black;
       item.parent.parent.color=Red;
       uncle.color=Black;
       continue;
    }//close if
```

You correctly flip the colors but do not re-assign item for the next trip through the loop, item should be items' grandparent during the next iteration, so make it:

```
            if(uncle.color==Red && uncle!=nil) {   //the uncle needs to exist and and be red to recolored
               item.parent.color=Black;
               item.parent.parent.color=Red;
               uncle.color=Black;
item = item.parent.parent;
               continue;
            }//close if
```

This change is needed for both uncle cases (item.parent is a left and right child).